# Best practice for communicating between docker containers

Tags: docker, websocket, communication, volume

I have two containers in my application running on a Raspberry pi. One container is a python container that takes sporadic input from I/O devices. The other container is running Electron JS. My question is what is the best way to push the data received by the python container from the I/O devices to the Electron JS app? I’m in between writing to a shared volume and using a websocket to communicate between the two containers, but don’t know which way is better, and why.

Comment: Can you explain how are you using websocket for communication between two containers? Have you created both containers in the same network?
Docker volumes will be better idea anyway as you won't be dependent on networking.

Comment: Yes, the two containers are on the same network, on the same device, running on an IoT platform called balena, which was easy to set up a shared volume. I had difficulty with the networking, as the socket connection kept on closing when different html pages were returned from the Electron App. This could also be because I'm not very familiar with js and had implemented it incorrectly. I guess I'm wondering if sticking with the easier way of using a volume is programmatically a less elegant solution than networking, and if I should invest the time to figuring it out, or if it matters at all

Comment: If you want to share data between containers the best idea is to use volumes if possible and in that case, networking doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to use a network connection; you mention Websockets, but a plain HTTP connection works just fine and is a little easier to manage.

The setup for this is fairly straightforward.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has a reasonable description of the setup, even if you're not using Compose: arrange for a Docker network to exist (Compose does this automatically), and then the other container's name (Compose service name, `docker run --name`) is usable as a host name.  If you're using Compose you don't need to do any setup at all and a bare-bones `docker-compose.yml` will work:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  container-a:
    build: a
  container-b:
    build: b
```

If you're not using Compose then you need to manually create the network, which roughly looks like

```sh
docker network create some-net
docker run --net some-net --name container-a ...
docker run --net some-net --name container-b ...
```

In both cases, in those two containers, `container-a` and `container-b` are valid host names resolving to the respective container.

I would not try to use a shared filesystem or a Unix socket here.  The shared-volume setup is more complex and requires some additional setup to make sure permissions are correct; TCP networking doesn't.  It also comes with a hard requirement that both containers are on the same physical node and that there is only one server.  If you're looking forward to clustered environments like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes, the same TCP/HTTP networking mechanism will work (even though the setup can be very different) but the cluster environment can provide a load balancer so that you can have multiple copies of the server, and there's no particular requirement that the server and client be colocated.

Comment: Just tested with two containersin the same network and I can't ping one from the other. The name resolution fails